# Rigidbody2D Circular Orbiting

Tags: 2d, physics, unity, rigidbody

I am trying to create a basic solar system in 2D. All space objects has *CircleCollider2D* on them *(which are required for raycasting in another script)*. Currently planets are childs of stars, and satellites are childs of planets. This is the code I am currently using on planets and satellites:

```
void Update () 
{    
    transform.localPosition = Quaternion.AngleAxis(speed*Time.deltaTime, -Vector3.forward) * transform.localPosition;
}
```

This code basically rotates the GameObject around it's parent on a fixed velocity while keeping the distance at the beginning.

This setup does exactly what I want, but the problem is this:

[image: Profile results]

After some research, I learned this:

> When you move an object with a collider and without a rigidbody, the complete static collision data needs to be recalculated, which is slow.

So moving GameObjects that has colliders via transforms (which I do in code above) causes this horrible workload.

So I need to do the exact same thing with Rigidbody2D, but I have absolutely no idea how to, I have tried a few things but they either caused objects to move out of orbit or draw spirals going out of orbits.

Thanks in advance.

*Note: It is not mandatory for me to parent planets to stars and satellites to planets. So if you have a solution that requires not to parent objects to each other, please don't hesitate to post them.*

---

**Edit:**

First of all, I didn't manage to do what I want with physics engine.

But while experimenting, I discovered that, you don't necessarily have to "move" transform via Rigidbody to prevent collider re-creation; it is enough to have a Rigidbody attached to the GameObject. So if you have a Rigidbody attached to the GameObject, it doesn't matter if you use Transform or Rigidbody to move the GameObject, engine doesn't try to destroy and re-create Colliders.

So I think my problem is solved right now, but question still open for answers since the question itself is still unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something a while back for Unity 4 that does this. The code isn't the cleanest, and it needs to be updated to version 5, but it does what you want using Rigidbody2D.

I will update it over the next couple weeks and stick it on my [Custom Unity Library](https://github.com/Evorlor/Custom-Unity-Library) (if it's good enough). In the meanwhile, here is the script which you can reference, but I wouldn't really trust at this time. I wrote it while I was still learning Unity.

It extends Rigidbody2D. The MovePositionInCircle method is probably the most relevant to you. Perhaps the MovePositionInEllipse method.

Anyways, here it is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public static class RigidBody2DExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the velocity for the game object and all of its descendants.
    /// If a descendant does not have a Rigidbody2D, neither it nor any of its descendants will have their velocity changed.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetVelocityForDescendants(this Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D, Vector2 velocity)
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = velocity;
        foreach (Transform child in rigidbody2D.transform)
        {
            if (child.rigidbody2D)
            {
                child.rigidbody2D.SetVelocityForDescendants(velocity);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This ends any active calls of Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInLine() or Rigidbody2D.movePositionInCircle()
    /// </summary>
    public static void CancelMovePosition(this Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D)
    {
        RemoveExistingMovePositionComponents(rigidbody2D);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the RigidBody2D's gameobject in a straight line, for a specified duration, for a specified distance, and in a specified direction.
    /// Optionally, whether or not the Rigidbody2D should rotate towards the direction it is moving, whether or not to invert horizontal movement, and whether or not to invert vertical movement can be declared.
    /// If the distance is set to 0, the object will move in line until Rigidbody2D.CancelMovePosition(), Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInLine(), or Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInCircle() is called, and the Seconds will be the speed at pixels per second.
    /// When Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInCircle() is called, any pending calls of Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInCircle() or Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInLine() for that GameObject will be canceled.
    /// Rigidbody2D.MovePosition() will be unavailable until this call completes.
    /// </summary>
    public static void MovePositionInLine(this Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D, float seconds, float distance, Vector2 direction, bool rotate = true, bool invertHorizontalMovement = false, bool invertVerticalMovement = false)
    {
        RemoveExistingMovePositionComponents(rigidbody2D);

        MovePositionInLine movePositionInLine = rigidbody2D.gameObject.AddComponent<MovePositionInLine>();
        movePositionInLine.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInInspector;
        movePositionInLine.Seconds = seconds;
        movePositionInLine.Distance = distance;
        movePositionInLine.Direction = direction;
        movePositionInLine.Rotate = rotate;
        movePositionInLine.InvertHorizontalMovement = invertHorizontalMovement;
        movePositionInLine.InvertVerticalMovement = invertVerticalMovement;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the RigidBody2D's gameObject in a circle for a specified duration, with a specified radius, and starting in a specified direction.
    /// Optionally, the number of circles, whether or not the circle should be clockwise, whether or not the Rigidbody2D should rotate while moving, whether or not to invert horizontal movement, and whether or not to invert vertical movement can be declared.
    /// If the number of circles is set to 0, the object will move in circles until Rigidbody2D.CancelMovePosition(), Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInEllipse(), Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInLine(), or Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInCircle() is called, and the seconds will become the time it takes to complete a single circle.
    /// When Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInCircle() is called, any pending calls of Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInCircle(), Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInEllipse(), or Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInLine() for that GameObject will be canceled.
    /// Rigidbody2D.MovePosition() will be unavailable until this call completes.
    /// </summary>
    public static void MovePositionInCircle(this Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D, float seconds, float numberOfCircles, float radius, Vector2 startDirection, bool clockwise = true, bool rotate = true, bool invertHorizontalMovement = false, bool invertVerticalMovement = false)
    {
        rigidbody2D.MovePositionInEllipse(seconds, numberOfCircles, radius, startDirection, new Vector2(1.0F, 1.0F), clockwise, rotate, invertHorizontalMovement, invertVerticalMovement);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the RigidBody2D's gameObject in an ellipse for a specified duration, with a specified radius, starting in a specified direction, and shaped by the specified x and y modifier.
    /// Optionally, the number of ellipses, whether or not the ellipse should be clockwise, whether or not the Rigidbody2D should rotate while moving, whether or not to invert horizontal movement, and whether or not to invert vertical movement can be declared.
    /// If the number of ellipses is set to 0, the object will move in ellipses until Rigidbody2D.CancelMovePosition(), Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInLine(), Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInEllipse(), or Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInCircle() is called, and the seconds will become the time it takes to complete a single ellipse.
    /// When Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInEllipse() is called, any pending calls of Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInCircle(), Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInEllipse(), or Rigidbody2D.MovePositionInLine() for that GameObject will be canceled.
    /// Rigidbody2D.MovePosition() will be unavailable until this call completes.
    /// </summary>
    public static void MovePositionInEllipse(this Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D, float seconds, float numberOfCircles, float radius, Vector2 startDirection, Vector2 ellipticalMultiplier, bool clockwise = true, bool rotate = true, bool invertHorizontalMovement = false, bool invertVerticalMovement = false)
    {
        RemoveExistingMovePositionComponents(rigidbody2D);

        MovePositionInEllipse movePositionInEllipse = rigidbody2D.gameObject.AddComponent<MovePositionInEllipse>();
        movePositionInEllipse.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInInspector;
        movePositionInEllipse.Seconds = seconds;
        movePositionInEllipse.NumberOfCircles = numberOfCircles;
        movePositionInEllipse.Radius = radius;
        movePositionInEllipse.StartDirection = startDirection;
        movePositionInEllipse.EllipticalMultiplier = ellipticalMultiplier;
        movePositionInEllipse.Clockwise = clockwise;
        movePositionInEllipse.Rotate = rotate;
        movePositionInEllipse.InvertHorizontalMovement = invertHorizontalMovement;
        movePositionInEllipse.InvertVerticalMovement = invertVerticalMovement;
    }

    private static void RemoveExistingMovePositionComponents(Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D)
    {
        MovePositionInLine[] movePositionInLineComponents = rigidbody2D.gameObject.GetComponents<MovePositionInLine>();
        foreach (MovePositionInLine movePositionInLineComponent in movePositionInLineComponents)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(movePositionInLineComponent);
        }

        MovePositionInEllipse[] movePositionInEllipseComponents = rigidbody2D.gameObject.GetComponents<MovePositionInEllipse>();
        foreach (MovePositionInEllipse movePositionInEllipseComponent in movePositionInEllipseComponents)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(movePositionInEllipseComponent);
        }
    }
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
class MovePositionInLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Seconds { get; set; }
    public float Distance { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Direction { get; set; }
    public bool Rotate { get; set; }
    public bool InvertHorizontalMovement { get; set; }
    public bool InvertVerticalMovement { get; set; }

    private float distanceTraveled;
    private bool moveInfinitely;

    void Start()
    {
        float xDirection = InvertHorizontalMovement ? -Direction.x : Direction.x;
        float yDirection = InvertVerticalMovement ? -Direction.y : Direction.y;
        Direction = new Vector2(xDirection, yDirection);
        Direction = Direction.normalized;

        if (Distance == 0)
        {
            moveInfinitely = true;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Rotate)
        {
            float rotationAngle = Mathf.Atan2(Direction.y, Direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90.0F;
            Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationAngle, Vector3.forward);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, quaternion, Time.deltaTime * 360);
        }

        float speed = Seconds != 0 ? Distance / Seconds * Time.deltaTime : 0;
        if (Distance == 0)
        {
            speed = Seconds * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        Vector2 oldPosition = rigidbody2D.transform.position;
        Vector2 newPosition = oldPosition + Direction * speed;
        rigidbody2D.MovePosition(newPosition);

        distanceTraveled += Vector2.Distance(oldPosition, newPosition);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        bool movementComplete = distanceTraveled >= Distance && !moveInfinitely;
        if (movementComplete)
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
class MovePositionInEllipse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Seconds { get; set; }
    public float NumberOfCircles { get; set; }
    public float Radius { get; set; }
    public Vector2 StartDirection { get; set; }
    public Vector2 EllipticalMultiplier { get; set; }
    public bool Clockwise { get; set; }
    public bool Rotate { get; set; }
    public bool InvertHorizontalMovement { get; set; }
    public bool InvertVerticalMovement { get; set; }

    private float angle = 0;
    private float xOffset;
    private float yOffset;
    private float startAngle;
    private bool moveInfinitely;

    void Start()
    {
        float xDirection = InvertHorizontalMovement ? -StartDirection.x : StartDirection.x;
        float yDirection = InvertVerticalMovement ? -StartDirection.y : StartDirection.y;
        StartDirection = new Vector2(xDirection, yDirection);
        Clockwise = !Clockwise;

        StartDirection = StartDirection.normalized;
        EllipticalMultiplier = EllipticalMultiplier.normalized;
        angle = StartDirection.ToRadians();
        if (Clockwise)
        {
            xOffset = StartDirection.y * Radius * EllipticalMultiplier.x + rigidbody2D.transform.position.x;
            yOffset = -(StartDirection.x * Radius * EllipticalMultiplier.y) + rigidbody2D.transform.position.y;
        }
        else
        {
            xOffset = -(StartDirection.y * Radius * EllipticalMultiplier.x) + rigidbody2D.transform.position.x;
            yOffset = StartDirection.x * Radius * EllipticalMultiplier.y + rigidbody2D.transform.position.y;
            angle += Mathf.PI;
        }
        startAngle = angle;

        if (NumberOfCircles == 0)
        {
            NumberOfCircles = 1;
            moveInfinitely = true;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Clockwise)
        {
            if (NumberOfCircles != 0)
            {
                angle -= Seconds != 0 ? 2 * Mathf.PI / Seconds * NumberOfCircles * Time.deltaTime : 0;
            }
            else
            {
                angle -= Seconds * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (NumberOfCircles != 0)
            {
                angle += Seconds != 0 ? 2 * Mathf.PI / Seconds * NumberOfCircles * Time.deltaTime : 0;
            }
            else
            {
                angle += Seconds * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        Vector3 oldPosition = rigidbody2D.transform.position;
        float newX = Mathf.Cos(angle) * Radius * EllipticalMultiplier.x + xOffset;
        float newY = Mathf.Sin(angle) * Radius * EllipticalMultiplier.y + yOffset;
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector2(newX, newY);

        if (Rotate)
        {
            Vector3 direction = oldPosition - newPosition;
            float rotationAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 90.0F;
            Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationAngle, Vector3.forward);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, quaternion, Time.deltaTime * 360);
        }
        rigidbody2D.MovePosition(newPosition);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        bool movementComplete = Mathf.Abs(angle - startAngle) >= NumberOfCircles * 2 * Mathf.PI && !moveInfinitely;
        if (movementComplete)
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simplistic way of handling simplified orbits.

Define distance for each Celestial body.

R=35000 km

Integrate Theta

Theta=Theta + 0.1

Plot Point by converting Polar to Rectangle

X=R*cos(Theta)
Y=R*sin(Theta)

Want a more realistic process just ask.